# Unable to boot due to GNOME Power Manager error

Tags: login, login-screen

Really am stuck here. I have scoured the net and this seems a fairly common issue pointing to root space. On start up everything seems fine and i get to my users log in page with the 2 users names. However in the bottom right corner is the message in the title. If i log in it just refreshes and goes back to the same log in page.

I have pressed ctrl alt F1 as per the posts and logged in with the IT password set on this pc. However when i enter sudo apt-get clean the system then asks me for a sudo password.

As far as we are aware there is no sudo password on this pc and if there was there are only 3 passwords i ever use and none of them work. I can run other sudo commands however it does not ask me for a password. I have also run the df -h and it looks like i am at 100% as per others posts. Can anyone suggest how i can get around the sudo password or clean up space another way?

Thanks J

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the user's password? I was unsure from your explanation if you tried re-entering that user's password, and if I missed that, my apologies.

Comment: hi i have tried the users passord and the 3 other passwords we have. if i get the password wrong it gives me 3 attempts. If i put the users password in it doesnt say wrong password but takes me back to the original prompt an....we@ACH-Server: ~$ once back here it will not let me enter sudo apt-get clean it simply does nothing but moves down the line and back to the prompt an....we@ACH-Server:~$

Comment: It drops you to the prompt, because the apt-get clean command has no output. It worked for you, but you don't see the result because there wasn't anything to clean.

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

- Live cd: Boot a live cd, open a terminal, run `sudo tune2fs -m 0.5 /dev/sda1` (If your first partition is low on space, and is on ext filesystem. You can check this with a `df -T` command.) This will regain the root reserved free space, and you can boot normally to clear some more. This will only work on ext[2,3,4]. On the live CD there is no password for sudo, just hit enter-.
- Recovery mode: After POST, hold down right shift button until GRUB menu appears, select recovery mode. When you get to the menu, remount everything as rw (there is an option for that). And select root. If you haven't set any root password, it will drop you to the root shell immediately. Run `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoremove`. Here you can also run the command written in the live cd solution.

**Update**
As you can log in normally on tty1, run the `sudo tune2fs -m 0.5 /dev/sda1` (please replace the partition with the one on which you are low on space)

Let me know if you had any problems.

Comment: ill try that but my technical skills are somewhat limited shall we say. Thanks for the posts guys

Comment: As sudo works, just execute the command. you can check the free space and type with `df -T`

Comment: came up with a message "setting reserved blocks percentage to 0.5% (1244 blocks)" what should i do now ?

Comment: That is good. Now check the free space. There sould be enough to boot normally.

Comment: ill try but it does not look like much has changed on the available it still shows as 0% used 100%

Comment: still coming up with the gnome power error on reboot and simply refreshes or goes to a black screen :-(

Comment: can you post a 'df -T'

Comment: /dev/mapper/ACH--Server-root

Comment: this is not the full output. But as I see, you have an lvm setup. Change the `/dev/sda1` to your lvm logical volume `/dev/mapper/ACH--Server-root` in the command. Or if you have one for home, do the same with that also.

Comment: /dev/mapper/ACH--Server-root
    ext3     75973728  72130820 0 100% /
none    devtmpfs   503108       304 502804   1% /dev
none    tmpfs      507696         4 507692   1% /dev/shm
none    tmpfs      507696       336 507360   1% /var/run
none     tmpfs      507696         0 507696   0% /var/lock
none     tmpfs      507696         0 507696   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda/5 ext2       233335     56738 175353  25% /boot

/home/an...we/.Private
 ecryptfs    75973728  72130820 0 100% /home/an...we

Comment: grr cant get it to paste in a nice easy box format

Comment: ext3     75973728  72130820 0 100% /

Comment: none    devtmpfs   503108       304 502804   1% /dev

Comment: none    tmpfs      507696         4 507692   1% /dev/shm

Comment: none    tmpfs      507696       336 507360   1% /var/run

Comment: none     tmpfs      507696         0 507696   0% /var/lock

Comment: none     tmpfs      507696         0 507696   0% /lib/init/rw

Comment: /dev/sda/5 ext2       233335     56738 175353  25% /boot

Comment: /home/an...we/.Private

Comment: ecryptfs    75973728  72130820 0 100% /home/an...we

Comment: gajdipajti you are a legend my friend. The pc is back up and running. It now shows as 96% so 4% of space its only a matter of time before this is full again what is the best way to increase the space so this never happens again. The pc is only used for internet and emails and the odd xcel or word file.

Comment: Buy an extra hdd. Install it. Use system-config-lvm to add the extra drive to the volume group, and expand. This is easy, and can be done via graphical interface.

Or delete some files. There is no other way.